# Retrieving Primary Key, Identity column, and specific name column from Database tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get primary key (if present), identity (if present), and column named 'ID' (if present) from every table in selected database. I got SQL query to do the work, but query returns records where Primary Key sometimes has both "No" and "Yes" values. Thus, resulting in multiple rows of data, so I used word DISTINCT to remove duplicates. I am assuming this is due to Indexes defined on some columns.

How would it be possible to fix this?

SQL query used:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    object_name(i.object_id) [Table], 
    c.name [Column], 
    IIF(i.is_primary_key = 1, 'Yes', 'No') [PK], 
    IIF(c.is_identity = 1, 'Yes', 'No') [Identity],
    IIF(UPPER(c.name) = 'ID', 'Yes', 'No') [Named ID]
FROM sys.indexes i
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = i.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.identity_columns idc ON idc.object_id = c.object_id AND idc.column_id = c.column_id
WHERE 
    i.is_primary_key = 1 OR c.is_identity = 1 OR c.name = 'ID'
ORDER BY [Table];
```

Comment: I don't understand your query here. Are you trying all columns that are a primary key, an identity or named ID? What do you want to happen for composite keys?

Comment: I need to check all tables for a column that may be used as unique identifier. Primary key on a column means that PK will be used. If PK is not found than Identity (auto-increment) row would be used. Finally, if no PK or auto-increment (identity) column then column named "ID" would be used. So PK > Identity > "ID" named column. Thus, I need list with this information about each table.

Comment: Columns are ALWAYS named.

Comment: Column must be named "ID" (in case PK or Identity is missing on the table). If the column is named something else I do not care about that column unless it happens to be Primary Key or Identity. However, I want full list of all PK, Identity, and columns with name "ID" and then just Yes/No for each value to signify whether that column is PK, Identity, or named ID or any combination of these.

Comment: Since you want this kind of information for every table you should start your query with sys.tables. Then find the columns in that table that meet your criteria. Use a left join so you can still see those tables that have no matching criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone needing something similar in the future, I adopted version of Peter's answer (including advice from Sean Lange to use sys.tables):

```
SELECT 
    t.name AS [Table], 
    c.name AS [Column], 
    CASE i.is_primary_key WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END [PK], 
    CASE idc.is_identity WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END [Identity],
    CASE c.name WHEN 'ID' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END [Named ID]
FROM 
    sys.tables t 
    LEFT JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.identity_columns idc ON idc.object_id = t.object_id AND idc.column_id = c.column_id AND idc.is_identity = 1
    LEFT JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = t.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.object_id = t.object_id AND i.index_id = ic.index_id AND i.is_primary_key = 1
WHERE t.type = 'U' AND (idc.is_identity = 1 OR i.is_primary_key = 1 OR c.name = 'ID')
ORDER BY t.name, c.name;
```

Comment: If you need schema info and do not mind extra complexity added to your query, you can also take a look at solution from Hector Diaz.

Answer (score 0):

You are using sys.indexes. A table can have multiple indexes and a column can be used multiple indexes. What your query is telling you is that the column is used in the PK index and also in another index (which is not the PK index).

Also your query is excluding all columns that are not in an index.

Start with sys.columns and use outer joins instead. Object id is the id of the table, not of the column, so you need index_columns aswell.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    object_name(c.object_id) [Table], 
    c.name [Column], 
    i.is_primary_key,
    case i.is_primary_key when 1 then 'Yes' else 'No'end [PK], 
    case c.is_identity when 1 then 'Yes' else 'No'end [Identity],
    case c.name when 'ID' then 'Yes' else 'No'end [Named ID]
FROM sys.columns c
    left join sys.index_columns ic on  c.column_id = ic.column_id and c.object_id = ic.object_id
    left JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.index_id = ic.index_id and c.object_id = i.object_id  and i.is_primary_key= 1
    left JOIN sys.identity_columns idc ON idc.object_id = c.object_id AND idc.column_id = c.column_id
WHERE i.is_primary_key = 1 OR c.is_identity = 1 OR c.name = 'ID'
ORDER BY [Table];
```

Comment: Hi Peter, I realised indexes were the problem. But how would I be able to fix this. Is it possible to filter indexes out?

Comment: Would you be able to suggest how to fix this, or suggest a better approach to obtaining the information I need? Thank you.

Comment: @SamirSuljkanovic I've updated my answer, including a query.

Comment: Thank you. I ran the suggested query and I am getting rows with incorrect information for Primary Keys (some columns are flagged as Primary Keys while in fact they are not).

Comment: @SamirSuljkanovic I updated once more. You need table sys.index_columns aswell since object id is not the id of the column.

Comment: Thank you Peter. This query seems to be working to my expectation.

Comment: Sorry, but it seems the query actually is not what I expected. After carefully examining everything it seems this query is producing similar results to the one I started with, but with exception that you are filtering out everything that is not Primary Key - but I need even those columns that are not Pk, but may be identity or named "ID".

Comment: @SamirSuljkanovic It is working on the databases I tested on. Only problem I had was that it was not showing the tablename for columns without PK, but I've resolved that now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following query, however you could get results where multiple columns form the primary key like the following:

[image: Multiple columns form the primary key]

because of something like:

```
ALTER TABLE [derived].[LocationParameterMedium] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_LocationParameterMedium] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CycleID] ASC, [LocationID] ASC, [ParameterID] ASC, [MediumID] ASC)
GO
```

Which can be fixed by rolling up the columns into a single column, the [following link explains how to roll-up columns into a single column](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2914/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-column-for-sql-server-data/)

Query:

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id) AS [Schema], -- Incase there is mulple schemas and same table name
    t.name AS [Table], 
    c.name AS [Column], 
    IIF((SELECT 1 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE keyCU
        WHERE keyCU.COLUMN_NAME = c.name 
            AND keyCU.TABLE_SCHEMA = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id)
            AND keyCU.TABLE_NAME = t.name
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(keyCU.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + QUOTENAME(keyCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME)), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1) = 1, 'Yes', 'No') [PK], 
    IIF(c.is_identity = 1, 'Yes', 'No') [Identity],
    IIF(c.name = 'ID', 'Yes', 'No') [Named ID]
FROM sys.tables AS t
LEFT JOIN sys.columns AS c
    ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    AND (c.is_identity = 1
        OR c.name = 'ID' 
        OR EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE keyCU
                    WHERE keyCU.COLUMN_NAME = c.name 
                        AND keyCU.TABLE_SCHEMA = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id)
                        AND keyCU.TABLE_NAME = t.name
                        AND OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(keyCU.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + QUOTENAME(keyCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME)), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
                  )
    )
---- To exclude tables where there is no PK, identity, or column name = 'ID' 
--WHERE c.name IS NOT NULL
```